# How do I open scripts with double-click without them logging out after all commands are executed?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to make a .command script that will call another script.
So whenever I double-click that script, it should launch another one.

```
source /bin/name.sh
```

Whenever I double click that file, it invokes that script without any problem.
But after all commands are executed, it is logging out.

```
logout

[Process completed]
```

I have also noticed this whenever i open .command file:

`~/name.command ; exit;`

I have made menu with aliases, So for example whenever user types in "Name" in console, it opens Name.sh.

Is there any way I can launch that script with double-clicking? So script will not log out after all commands are done. It doesn't close window, it just simply logs out from window, and then i can't access shell anymore.

Comment: How about putting `read -n 1 -s` at the end of the script?  Something like that should wait for a keypress before terminating.

Comment: Yes it is working, But i have made menu script with aliases, So whenever user types "name" it executes "name.sh", But that script will terminate on keypress.

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to act as an example? I'm unclear on exactly what you're describing, and an example should clear things up nicely.

Comment: So il explain situation first: I have made .command file, In this command file there is bash script that just will open another script (name.sh) which is located in v

Comment: Are you seeking to have a new interactive terminal window after the commands complete?  Or are you simply not wanting the terminal window to close automatically?  With the Terminal app, you can use the preferences to set it so that the window doesn't close when the shell exits, or so that it does close when the shell exits, or so that it closes when the shell exits successfully.  It's a setting in the 'shell' tab under the 'profiles' section of the preferences, and has a drop down choice of 3 options.

Comment: Is there any way i can change those preferences in Terminal? with specific command.

Comment: I have set aliases, So user can use it as menu, i just don't want terminal to automatically quit when all commands are invoked. As i said it just shows [ Process Completed ] text and user can't access command line.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik OS X will only close the opened terminal if the command successes, so adding `exit 1` to your file should do the trick:

```
if something;
  stuff1
else;
  stuff2
fi
# Make sure the exit with error to prevent terminal closing
exit 1
```

Comment: Well i tried adding "exit 1" but it logged out again, However i also don't want script to show error messages. I would try while (true) do loop, but i need some command that won't show anything at all.

Comment: It's configurable — for the Terminal, you can choose between not closing until you close the window, closing window on sucess, and always closing the window.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your problem...

Don't use `source` to launch your *sub-commands*; `source` execute in the current shell the commands in the given script, so that if one of them uses `exit` your current shell will exit. Just launch it as a simple command, i.e. `/bin/name.sh` that should be sufficient (if the script is readable and executable).

Comment: Well the executable file that i have made is under .command extension, So whenever i double click it, It will open another script (name.sh for example), But if i manually open name.sh from terminal, It will not logout.